# Using RavenDB PutCommand to update an existing document

Tags: ravendb

If I insert a new document into RavenDB using a put command and specify it's key, the first time it is simply inserted as expected. However, the second time I run the same put command with the same key, but altered data there is a new document created, I was expecting the existing document to be updated.

This seems to come from the fact that the document key has an incrementing number attached to the end of it (not by me, I guess the raven client is doing it for me).

How can I prevent the additional number from being appended to my document key so that a put command updates rather than creates a document?

Comment: Are you trying to save a document with a key ending with a slash?

Comment: yes I was, did I stumble into a well known problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create keys with a / in the end.
See the docs here: http://ravendb.net/docs/theory/document-key-generation